# Semantic UI: How to AutoClose Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

what I want to have, is a Success Modal which closes automatically after 2s.
When I use delay() that doesnt matter. It closes immediately after opening.

```
 $('.ui.modal.success')
    .modal('show')
    .delay(2000)
    .modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has an effects queue which is used for queueing animations on elements (like `.slideUp` or `.animate`). [`.delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) is treated as an animation that is added to the effects queue of an element that does nothing for the amount of time specified (in your case, 2 seconds). Since `.modal('hide')` is not an animation, it is not added to the effects queue. In other words, it is completed instantly.

One solution is to add it to the effects queue manually using [`.queue`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`.dequeue`](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/):

```
$('.ui.modal.success')
    .modal('show')
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).modal('hide').dequeue();
    });
```

If you want to learn more about jQuery effects, I'd suggest reading the [Effects pages in the jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.ui.modal.success').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
        $this.modal('hide');
    }, 2000));
});
```